# decodeURIComponent(uri) is not working?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, urlencode, encodeuricomponent

I'm using Ajax to post contents, and I'm using `http.send(encodeURIComponent(params));` for encoding ... but I'm unable to decode them in PHP. I'm using POST so I didn't think it required encode? I'm confused as to how I'm supposed to decode the values in PHP...

```
params = "guid="+szguid+"&username="+szusername+"&password="+szpassword+"&ip="+ip+"&name="+name+"&os="+os;
        //alert(params);
        document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';//change cursor to wait

        if(!http)
            http = CreateObject();  

        nocache = Math.random();

        http.open('post', 'addvm.php');
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        http.onreadystatechange = SaveReply;
       http.send(encodeURIComponent(params));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`encodeURIComponent` will encode all the &s and =s that delimit your key/value pairs. You need to use it on each part individually. Like so:

```
 params = 
 "guid="      + encodeURIComponent(szguid)     + 
 "&username=" + encodeURIComponent(szusername) +
 "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(szpassword) +
 "&ip="       + encodeURIComponent(ip)         +
 "&name="     + encodeURIComponent(name)       +
 "&os="       + encodeURIComponent(os);
    //alert(params);
    document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';//change cursor to wait

    if(!http)
        http = CreateObject();  

    nocache = Math.random();

    http.open('post', 'addvm.php');
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    http.onreadystatechange = SaveReply;
    http.send(params);
```

Comment: No you don't. You want to do this in JavaScript. It is unnecessarily difficult and downright pointless to do in PHP.

Comment: @minitech: okies :) but how? like i m using $username = trim($_POST["username"]); $password = $_POST["password"]; $ip = trim($_POST["ip"]); $name = trim($_POST["name"]); $os = trim($_POST["os"]); $hostid = "Physical"; in php how to decode them ... after that my all fields able to take + and & string ?

Comment: @Stan: Okay, NO! Do not decode them in PHP. Let me make this clear: you are sending the values incorrectly in your JavaScript. You can't just use `encodeURIComponent` on all of your parameters, you have to do them separately.

Comment: @ minitech: okies but how i m able to send it separately ?in an encoded form, i think u r right i make some mistaks in encoding

Comment: @Stan: See my edited post for how you're supposed to encode the components.

Comment: minitech :) solve my problem thanks u very much ............ tk cr .... !!!!!  ...stackoverflow is gr8

Answer (score 1):

If you're submitting encoded values from JS and want to `decode` them in PHP you can do something like:

```
// decode POST values so you don't have to decode each pieces one by one
$_POST = array_map(function($param) {
            return urldecode($param);
        }, $_POST);

// assign post values after every value is decoded
```

Comment: can I use $_GET (substitute all the $_POST to $_GET for your script above) ??

Comment: @bungdito codewise yes, but it will not be a good practice. I also don't see a reason why you need to do that.