# Unable to extract post arguments after encodeURIComponent()

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, urlencode

I encoded a parameter string from the fields collected by a form using `encodeURIComponent()` and then sent it to the server using `XMLHttpRequest`.

In the server side PHP script I'm using `extract(urldecode($_POST), EXTR_SKIP);` to extract the parameters to variables.

Although the process was working fine before I added the encoding of the URI component, the variables are now not being extracted on the server. What am I doing wrong please?

This is the JavaScript which does the sending:

```
function postData(url, parameters, postprocess, displayURL, runOnError) {

    // Check whether user action has already failed validation
    if (typeof cancel !== 'undefined') {

        // Deleting a variable only works if a global
        delete cancel;
        return false;

    }

    var
        xmlHttp = AJAX(),
        resp,
        defcon,
        json;

    parameters = EncodeURIComponent(parameters);

    if( url.charAt( 0 ) === '&' ) {

        url = url.slice( 1 );

    }

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange =  function(){

        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {

            resp = xmlHttp.responseText;

            checkSessionTimeout(resp);

            // REDIRECT TO POST-PROCESSORS
            if (postprocess !== '') {

                // Goto custom post processing function
                eval(unescape(postprocess));

            }

            // Determine whether json response or not
            else if ( resp.charAt( 0 ) == '{' ) {

                // it's json so redirect to...
                jsonGenericRespHandler(resp, displayURL);

            } else {

                // Use generic post process

                /* The following is depreciated. We should
                 * be using jsonGenericRespHandler(resp).
                 */

                if      (resp.toLowerCase().indexOf('error') > -1)      defcon = 'error';
                else if (resp.toLowerCase().indexOf('success') > -1)    defcon = 'success';
                else if (resp.toLowerCase().indexOf('warn') > -1)       defcon = 'warn';
                else                                                    defcon = 'info';

                // Make sure we don't miss an important message.
                if (defcon === 'warn' || defcon === 'error') {

                    alert(resp);
                    eval(runOnError);

                } else {

                    // Redirect to dashboard
                    if (displayURL === '') {

                        ajaxLoader('main/home.php', 'contentMain');

                    } else if (displayURL !== 0) {

                        ajaxLoader(displayURL, 'contentMain');

                    }

                    showMessage(defcon, resp);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters.length);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xmlHttp.send(parameters);
}
```

I should probably mention that the reason I added encodeURIComponent() was because I noticed that if the visitor entered a legitimate ampersand in the form, it was being treated as an extra argument on the server.

Comment: I'm pretty sure PHP automatically decodes any data sent, so you don't have to.

Comment: how are you sending them in the `XMLHTTPRequest`? In the url, or in the `req.send()`? Can you post your JS

Comment: urldecode takes a string not an array also php already handles the decoding.

Comment: Thanks @Musa. Have removed `urldecode()` on the server-side. Still no parameters being extracted though. 
 
@bokonic I have added to my question, the script which does the sending on the clientside.

Comment: I think I've found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6053488/1288274  
 
In a nutshell, it would appear that I should be encoding each of the parameter value/pairs individually, rather than as a group.